# The tilde operator in C

Tags: c++, c, operators

I've seen the tilde operator used in the ELF hashing algorithm, and I'm curious what it does. (The code is [from Eternally Confused](http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx).)

```
unsigned elf_hash ( void *key, int len )
{
  unsigned char *p = key;
  unsigned h = 0, g;
  int i;

  for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    h = ( h << 4 ) + p[i];
    g = h & 0xf0000000L;

    if ( g != 0 )
      h ^= g >> 24;

    h &= ~g;
  }

  return h;
}
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The `~` operator is bitwise [NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT), it inverts the bits in a binary number:

```
NOT 011100
  = 100011
```

Comment: What purpose would this serve? I heard you could use it in unsigned -> signed conversion but I don't see how?

Comment: Bitwise NOT is useful for a number of things, for example, bit masks.  I am not sure what you mean by unsigned to signed integer conversion.

Comment: Wait, aren't you supposed to AND the bitmask? that's how my bit reader is doing it, but it's touchy.

I read that if you have X and NOT it, then subtract one you'll get the unsigned version of a signed number, is that not correct?

Comment: I use bitwise NOT on a bitmask in combination with AND to clear specific bits prior to altering them.

Comment: Someone asked about "unsigned to signed conversion". The operation performed by `~` is also called the "one's complement", which is one form of binary negation.  Virtually all modern computers use two's complement arithmetic, which is the bitwise inverse, plus one.  So for a signed integer variable `x`, you will typically find that `~x + 1` gives the same value as `-x`. For example, `printf("%hx %hx\n", -1234, ~1234 + 1)` prints `fb2e fb2e` on my machine.

Comment: @MarcusJ Yes, one's complement works for converting signed to unsigned (signed->unsigned). (Note though it's easier to just assign the value to a variable declared differently and lett the compiler worry about it.) But it does _not_ work the other way around (unsigned->signed), partly because the possible unsigned values span a wider range than can be crammed into a signed variable, and partly because that problem is not well-defined without specifying -from outside information probably- what sign to invent. Your two comments got different replies because they specify opposite directions.

Answer (score 48):

`~` is the bitwise NOT operator. It inverts the bits of the operand.

For example, if you have:

```
char b = 0xF0;  /* Bits are 11110000 */
char c = ~b;    /* Bits are 00001111 */
```

Answer (score 12):

This is the bitwise NOT operator.
It flips all the bits in a number: 100110 -> 011001

Answer (score 9):

The tilde character is used as an operator to invert all bits of an integer (bitwise NOT).

For example: `~0x0044 = 0xFFBB`.

Answer (score 7):

It is the bitwise NOT operator. It inverts all bits in an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

Tilde operator (~) **also** called bitwise NOT operator,  performs **one's complement** of any binary number as argument. If the operand to NOT is decimal number then it convert it as binary and perform's one's complement operation.

To calculate one's complement simply invert all the digit [0-->1] and [1-->0] 
Ex : 0101 = 5;  ~(0101) = 1010.
Use of tilde operator : 
1. It is used in masking operation , Masking means setting and resetting the values inside any register . for ex :

```
char mask ;
mask = 1 << 5 ;
```

It will set mask to a binary value of 10000  and this mask can be used to check the bit value present inside other variable .

```
int a = 4;
int k = a&mask ; if the 5th bit is 1 , then k=1 otherwise k=0.
```

This is called **Masking** of bits.
2.To find binary equivalent of any number using masking properties.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void equi_bits(unsigned char);
int main()
{
    unsigned char num = 10 ;
    printf("\nDecimal %d is same as binary ", num);
    equi_bits(num);
    return 0; 
} 
void equi_bits(unsigned char n)
{
  int i ; 
  unsigned char j , k ,mask ;
  for( i = 7 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
  {
     j=i;
     mask = 1 << j;
     k = n&mask ; // Masking
     k==0?printf("0"):printf("1");
  }  
}
```

Output  : Decimal 10 is same as 00001010

**My observation** :For the maximum range of any data type , one's complement provide the negative value decreased by 1 to any corresponding value. 
ex:
 ~1 --------> -2
~2---------> -3
and so on... I will show you this observation using little code snippet

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a , b;
    a=10;
    b=~a; // b-----> -11    
    printf("%d\n",a+~b+1);// equivalent to a-b
    return 0;
}
Output: 0
```

Note : This is valid only for the range of data type. means for int data type this rule will be applicable only for the value of range[-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647].
 **Thankyou .....May this help you**