# What's the use of '~' in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, loops

```
#include<iostream.h>
void main()
{
   int x[]={1,2,3,4,5};
   for(int i=0;~i<5;i++)
      {    cout<<*x;
      }
}
```

When I run this program the display of console has infinite numbers of 1.
I didn't understand how this happened.Please kindly help me out of this program...
Is that due to the tilde operator, if its the reason then how?

Comment: it's the `Bitwise not` operator.

Comment: The bitwise `~` inverts the bits of its operand.

Comment: cout<<*x will always output 1. Are you sure you don't want x[i] instead?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207391/the-tilde-operator-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate [the tilde operator in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207391/the-tilde-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's due to a combination of the **bitwise NOT operator** (`~`) **and undefined behavior**.

Basically, `~i` will always be lower than `5` (well, than `0` in your case), since it will return a negative number for values of `i` greater than `0`. When you reach the maximum `int` number, `i++` will overflow and thus run into undefined behavior.

Until then though, you'll have `1` printed because that's what `*x` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Tilde is the bitwise inverse operator.  So ~0x00000000=0xFFFFFFFF or -1.  Increasing i would make this run for a very long time, a few billion iterations.

Answer (score 0):

The ~ operator is a bitwise NOT. Due to the signed nature of int, the bitwise NOT makes the number negative, which is less than 5. Get rid of it for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

the `~` operator is the BITWISE NOT boolean operator. So your loop is infinite becouse the counter is an `int32` and the result of the Bitwise NOT will always be a negative number.

Comment: " the result of the Bitwise NOT will always be a negative number" really?

Comment: not always in general but in this scenario is absolutely true, becouse the counter i starts from 0 and is of type signed integer.