# What does the macro _bnd(X,bnd) mean?

Tags: c, macros

Recently i read someone implement his own printf use the macro _bnd(x,bnd),but i don't understand what the mean of the macro.

```
#define _bnd(x, bnd) (sizeof(x) + (bnd) & ~(bnd))
```

i know the bitwise operator and the sizeof()

Comment: shouldn't it be `sizeof(x)`? (Note the case).

Comment: i think it checks sizeof(x), and stores the value in a number with the word length of BND. that could be a byte, int, short int, long int, double, etc

Comment: yes, it is sizeof(x),i misspell it

Comment: It would help your question if you showed in context how it was used.

Answer (score 0):

It's internal implementation magic, playing with implementation-dependent
properties of the addresses of the arguments to variable-argument
functions.

Unless you need to know what it all means, likely best to
stay away from it. Otherwise it may tempt you to rely on it.

And your macro should be

```
#define _bnd(X, bnd) (sizeof(X) + (bnd) & ~(bnd))
             ^
             check in your post
```

Also you can know by just expanding basic arrithmetic operation.For this you should know [sizeof()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) and [tilde operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207391/the-tilde-operator-in-c) and [bitwise operatior](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitwise.html).