# Meaning of tilde operator in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Consider

```
cv::Mat A;
cv::Mat B;   
//read images A and B
```

What is the meaning of following statement in OpenCV/C++

```
 A &= ~B ;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207391/the-tilde-operator-in-c

Comment: does that class have no documentation?

Comment: I couldn't find that (for tilde operator)

Comment: (BTW, I'd bet it's just a member-wise use of the normal `~` operator.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That expression( `A &= ~B` ) in OpenCV could be used to **find movement/moved objects** in a continuous sequence of images.

**E.g.**

**1.  `Image A`**

[image: Image A]

**2. `Image B - circle moves left`**

[image: Image B]

**3. `Inverse of B => ~B`**

[image: Inv B]

**4. `A&=~B => movement or difference of sequenced images`**

[image: Movement]

Answer (score 2):

It's got the ordinary meaning. The OpenCV documentation indeed is unclear, the *operators* are listed under ["Matrix *expressions*"](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

```
A = A BitwiseAnd (BitwiseNot B)
```

Example:

> A = 1100
> B = 0101
>
> ~B = 1010
>
> A&~B = 1000