# What is ~ operator in opencv , C++?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, mat

I encountered the following while trying to convert some C++ code that uses OpenCV to Java. I'd like to know what the `~` operator does to the Mat object `gradient_grown` in the following code and what's the Java equivalent to this?

```
Mat edge_enhanced_mser      = ~gradient_grown & mser_mask;
```

Comment: Looks like the `NOT` operator

Comment: Why wouldn't you google something like this?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions

Comment: if it's an overloaded operator, then why don't look into its source code, or maybe its documentation

Comment: How'd I do the same in Java?

Comment: In Java, you don't overload operators. You write a method, and try to give it a sane name.

Comment: **Note to future readers:** this is asking about an overloaded operator in a particular library, **not the built-in operator**!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the equivalent of the [bitwise NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT) operator overloaded for the `Mat` class. In this case, it will invert all bits in the matrix. It is listed in the section Matrix Expressions in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions):

> Bitwise logical operations: A logicop B, A logicop s, s logicop A, ~A, where logicop is one of :  &, |, ^.

In Java, you can use the [`bitwise_not()` method](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#bitwise_not%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat%29):

> bitwise_not
>
> public static void bitwise_not(Mat src, Mat dst)
>
> Inverts every bit of an array.

Note you need a new `Mat` to store the result:

```
bitwise_not(gradient_grown, gradient_grown_complement);
```

Comment: Even on an OpenCV `Mat` (whatever that is)?

Comment: Unless it's been overloaded for a class type, as it has here.

Comment: Thanks , I just found out a similar question with the same answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854370/meaning-of-tilde-operator-in-opencv