# Is calculation or condition checking yield a better performance

Tags: arrays, performance

This question contains a JavaScript example but it could possibly be relevant for other languages as well.

I got a 2d binary array (values are set to 1 and 0 only). I want to make an action which toggles all values, meaning turn all 0 to 1 and all 1 to 0.

Which is a better way to do it:

1)

```
for(var i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < colNum; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i][j] == 0)
            {
                arr[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

or

2)

```
for(var i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < colNum; j++)
        {
           arr[i][j] = 1 - arr[i][j];
        }
    }
```

I would like to know if there's a generic method which is best for most cases. Also, specifically regarding JS, is there a better way to do it than these 2 methods?

Comment: measure it..... but in general, if you can get rid of a branch(condition), do it!

Comment: Use **bitwise NOT** operator instead of subtraction, to avoid carry-problems with 2;s-complement arithmetic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207391/the-tilde-operator-in-c

Comment: In general avoiding conditional branches in your code will lead to better performance due to pipelining in modern processors.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: he wants zeros and ones, that clearly won't work.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Maybe; but it is not *a priori* obvious to me that OP knows what he wants.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: "values are set to 1 and 0 only" "turn all 0 to 1 and all 1 to 0" - *sigh*.. do you really want to question *that*? also, there are no carry-problems whatsoever.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Yes, actually. I think it's an x-y problem; and I note that English is not OP's native tongue, though he writes in it fairly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the second way of doing it, or I would use the xor operation, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        arr[i][j] ^= 1;
    }
}
```

The thing is, if statements translate into branching instructions which can be slow due to branch mispredictions. However, the performance gain in an example like this will barely show, and if it makes the code less readable, then it's not worth it. Always optimize last and if it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: @usr xor is just regular old logic, there's no excuse for not understanding it

Comment: @usr It would appear you're calling this "even more obfuscated" based on the premise that the original was "obfuscated" I don't really think it was.

Comment: XOR seems to be [slower](http://transtatic.com/blog/2013/03/swapping-values-in-c-tmp-variable-vs-xor-with-performance-times/)

Comment: Interesting. I suppose it depends on the architecture and the compiler/interpreter.

Comment: @Thomas that's about a xor swap vs a regular swap, the result is not surprising. But here we have neither, this is "xor with a constant" vs "compare and branch"