# Printing Bitwise NOT operator with hexadecimal format specifier

Tags: c

If i'm using `m` instead of `~m` then the code gives me the expected hexadecimal value of 32 but here it's giving `ffffffdf` as output.

**EDIT**
I know how bitwise `~` NOT operator works. But i'm not understanding this.Could somebody explain this...??

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int m = 32;
    printf("%x\n", ~m); //ffffffdf is printed as output

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what is `~` in C? You are saying you do. So what is the question?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: if you know how ~ works, then why are you asking this? You took an int, notted it, and asking why it's different...

Comment: @EugeneSh. ~32 will give me answer -33 using %d as a format specifier but here the format specifier is hexadecimal so i don't get it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [The tilde operator in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207391/the-tilde-operator-in-c)

Comment: @VivekMahto Google "two's complement"

Comment: @VivekMahto that's because if you print with a `%d` specifier, `0xffffffdf` is  hex for -33 as a **signed** integer. `%x` prints the hexadecimal representation of an integer, which is **unsigned**. There's no signed hexadecimal in programming because that wouldn't make any sense

Comment: Go Google and study "twos complement"

Comment: @AlexYan: That is actually not quite correct. Hex constants for instance are [promoted](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5) like positive integer values (but not like decimal constants). The hexadecimal _representation_, however is unsigned.

Comment: I think it's a fair question. It's not clear to everyone that integers are registers in C, rather than natural numbers represented with as many bits as nescessary.

Comment: @Olaf Yes representation and interpretation is what I meant if that wasn't clear enough in my previous comment. `ffffffdf` interpreted as a signed integer is -33, but is `ffffffdf` if it's interpreted as hex. So if you set the print specifier to `%d`, it'll be interpreted as a signed integer, and be printed as -33 etc

Comment: @claj Integers are *what* ? Many things are not clear to everyone, but it doesn't mean they all make a valid SO question.

Comment: @claj: Well, I learned about integer numbers in the very first years of school. I think they are pretty much "natural". (Not clear what you mean by "registers"). About the question: Accepting any simple question about something you will find in the very early chapters of any book about programming or Wikipedia would flood this site with mostly "random" noise and would render it almost useless.

Comment: But, @Olaf, as you already know then, the "natural" integers aren't of specific bit width. A ~ on a natural numbers "natural representation" would never render a higher value than the natural number itself. You probably didn't learn about computer number registers in your first schoolyears.

Comment: @claj: Well, that is the point with modulo-arithmetic, isn't it? And - as I already stated, it is handled very well in any book, Wikipedia and even in the standard for [fprintf](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8). Note, that `unsigned int` does not even have a signed representation (surprise, surprise), so the question is actually even nonsense for `%d` (as that takes `signed int`).

Comment: @claj Your answer is right and pretty good. But your comments are not making any sense, sorry.

Comment: @Olaf, well, I meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register, sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry, but neither does yours. Thanks. EOF

Comment: @claj: What have integer data types to do with processor registers? Prove me wrong, but the _abstract macine_ does not even state about an actual processor, nor does it require a CPU with registers actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, ~ is the bitwise-not operator. You said you understand how this operator works, but your question indicates that you do not. So let's go through this example:

First, you declare m to be an unsigned int, which happens to be 32 bits wide on your platform. You assign it the decimal value 32. The variable m is 0x00000020.

Then, you print it out. When you print it out normally, the expected output appears. But when you print it out with the ~ operator, you get something completely different.

The ~ (bitwise-not) operator does exactly what it says on the tin: It negates (flips) every bit, so 1s become 0s and 0s become 1s. Let's see what that would do to your number:

```
 m = 0b00000000000000000000000000100000 = 0x00000020
~m = 0b11111111111111111111111111011111 = 0xffffffdf
```

As you can see, the result exactly matches what is being output, which is good -- it means both your compiler and CPU are working as expected!

Answer (score 3):

Every hexadecimal digit is four bits. Since you got 8 hexadecimal digits your integers seems to be 8*4=32 bit.

The NOT of 32 = `000000000000000000000000000010000` would be something like `11111111111111111111111111101111` which would be the hexadecimal digits above.

Comment: `000000000000000000000000000010000` hex? That would be `F...FEFFFF`.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Ehm.. didn't he talk about hex? Sorry; if that is binary, he should have stated. Switching bases without clear statement is confusing.