# What can I do on c++ to do an inverse of a number?

Tags: c++

Im working on a RSA code and I rly dont know how to do the inverse of a number on c++. How you would you do it? There are some librarys that can help me to do it automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by inverse?  10 -> .1 or 10 -> 1?

Comment: additive inverse of multiplicative inverse?

Comment: multiplicative inverse

Comment: @mone `1/a` assuming `a` is your number

Comment: Did you do any research on this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7207391/2785528 -  is about the ~ operator ... which is a bitwise NOT, it inverts the bits in a binary number.

Comment: The modular multiplicative inverse you need for RSA (including a sample implementation for small numbers) has been [discussed previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20114154/179910).

Answer (score 2):

Here are several examples for *Modular multiplicative inverse* in C++:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiplicative-inverse-under-modulo-m/

> ```
> // C++ program to find multiplicative modulo inverse using 
> // Extended Euclid algorithm. 
> #include<iostream> 
> using namespace std; 
>   
> // C function for extended Euclidean Algorithm 
> int gcdExtended(int a, int b, int *x, int *y); 
>   
> // Function to find modulo inverse of a 
> void modInverse(int a, int m) 
> { 
>     int x, y; 
>     int g = gcdExtended(a, m, &x, &y); 
>     if (g != 1) 
>         cout << "Inverse doesn't exist"; 
>     else
>     { 
>         // m is added to handle negative x 
>         int res = (x%m + m) % m; 
>         cout << "Modular multiplicative inverse is " << res; 
>     } 
> } 
>   
> // C function for extended Euclidean Algorithm 
> int gcdExtended(int a, int b, int *x, int *y) 
> { 
>     // Base Case 
>     if (a == 0) 
>     { 
>         *x = 0, *y = 1; 
>         return b; 
>     } 
>   
>     int x1, y1; // To store results of recursive call 
>     int gcd = gcdExtended(b%a, a, &x1, &y1); 
>   
>     // Update x and y using results of recursive 
>     // call 
>     *x = y1 - (b/a) * x1; 
>     *y = x1; 
>   
>     return gcd; 
> } 
>   
> // Driver Program 
> int main() 
> { 
>     int a = 3, m = 11; 
>     modInverse(a, m); 
>     return 0; 
> }
> ```

Here's a good description of what it's doing:

[Modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)