# Modular Inverse Built-In, C++

Tags: c++, python-3.x, built-in, integer-arithmetic, modular-arithmetic

There is [a very nice way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9758173/11143763) to find a modular inverse (that is, such `b` that `ab ≡ 1 (mod m)` for given `a` and `m`) in [python-3.8](/questions/tagged/python-3.8):

```py
b = pow(a, -1, m)
```

`pow` is built-in in [python-3.8](/questions/tagged/python-3.8). Is there something like this in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)?

Comment: does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821181/what-can-i-do-on-c-to-do-an-inverse-of-a-number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do on c++ to do an inverse of a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821181/what-can-i-do-on-c-to-do-an-inverse-of-a-number)

Comment: see also this: [Modular Exponentiation for high numbers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207006/modular-exponentiation-for-high-numbers-in-c)

Comment: and to answer your question: no, afaik there is no such function in the standard library (ofc there is `std::pow` but it takes only 2 arguments, doesn't do modulo)

Comment: @JohnD, thank you, those posts help me, yet they do not answer my question - I stressed the **built-in** nature in my question.

Comment: @bolov, well, I guess, your **No** answers my question :). Alas. Yet, thank you.

Comment: ok ill resolve this then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no built-in function in C++ (to answer your question :) ).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the relatively standard library `boost` has function `boost::integer::mod_inverse`:

```cpp
#include <boost/integer/mod_inverse.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::integer::mod_inverse;

int main(void)
{
  int x = 3;
  int m = 5;

  int y = mod_inverse(x, m);

  std::cout << x << " ^-1 (mod " << m << ") = " << y << std::endl;;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 ^-1 (mod 5) = 2
```

References:

- [Source code for `boost::integer::mod_inverse`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/boost/integer/mod_inverse.hpp);
- [Documentation for `boost::integer::mod_inverse`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/mod_inverse.html).

Please note that `mod_inverse(x, m)` returns `0` if `a` and `m` are not coprime, whereas python's `pow(x, -1, m)` raises `ValueError: base is not invertible for the given modulus`.