# Calculate large multiplication and divide under modulus

Tags: c++, math, multiplication, division, modulo

In C++, I have a problem need to calculate `((a * b * c) / n) % m` with large a, b and c `(0 < a, b, c <= 10^9 and n, m > 0)`. And the problem guaranteed that  `a * b * c` is divisible by `n`.

I tried calc `((a * b) % m * c) % m) / n`  but it's not a right answer.

Comment: What are you using to do this "calc"?  How "large" are these numbers?

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that `a*b*c` is divisible by `n`?

Comment: You can't pass the `% m` above a division bar like that. Consider for instance m = 6, n = 3, and numerator = 6k+3 for some k. Then (numerator / n) % m = (2k+1) % 6, but ((numerator % m) / n) % m = 1.

Comment: However, if n is coprime with m, then there exists an integer q which is called "the inverse of n modulo m", and such that `(numerator / n) % m = (numerator * q) % m` for any numerator. In python, you can find `q` as `pow(n, -1, m)`.

Comment: Actually, `((numerator % m) / n) % m = (numerator / n) % m` is true whenever n and m are coprime, and more-often-false-than-true when m and n are not coprime. See this related math question: [Division in modular arithmetic when multiplicative inverse does not exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3206669/division-in-modular-arithmetic-when-multiplicative-inverse-does-not-exist)

Comment: You need to calculate the multiplicative inverse of n modulo m. See extended Euclid's algorithm for that, or find a library function that will do it for you. It should be noted that not all residues n will have inverses modulo m so you'll have to decide what to do about that.

Comment: Also, instead of `((a * b) % m * c) % m)` you could write `(((a%m) * (b%m)) % m * (c%m)) % m)`

Comment: Minh Trung, Are `a, b, c` all >= 0 and `m, n` > 0?

Comment: See [Modular Inverse Built-In, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653209/modular-inverse-built-in-c) for a boost library function that computes the modular inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to keep removing the common factors in numerator and denominator by calculating gcd and dividing it out. It is illustrated in following python code. In C++, gcd can be easily calculated using extended euclid's algorithm.

```py
import math
def prod(a,b,c,n):
    num = [a,b,c]
    p = 1
    tmp = n
    for i in range(len(num)):
       g = math.gcd(num[i],tmp)
       num[i] /= g
       tmp /= g
       p = (p*num[i]) % n
    return p
```